# When restoring a database in SQL Server 2008, how to ignore the users?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I am importing a SQL Server 2000 database to my SQL Server 2008 server.

I don't want to import any user/permission information, is there a way to ignore this?

The current restoration is causing me issues as it has users tied to the db.

Answer (score 0):

A restore includes users and permissions.  You could restore the database in "dbo only" mode, which would give you time to remove all users before the database came back online.

Comment: Select "Restrict access to the restored database (WITH RESTRICTED_USER)" on the options tab

Answer (score 0):

The restore operation is a physical operation, it restores data *pages*. It really knows absolutely nothing about the meaning the pages. As it turns out, some of the pages belong to catalog views that store information about users and permissions. There is absolutely no way to restore only 'part' of the database, as in to ignore certain catalog views.

Can you detail exactly what are the 'issues' you encounter with the users after the restore?